# source compilation errors for openliberty and JPMS

Tags: java, module, java-platform-module-system, open-liberty

Does anybody else experience strange `Source compilation had errors` info messages when running an application with JPMS modules on openliberty. These are info messages I also see in my project:

```
...\src\main\java\module-info.java:5: Fehler: Modul nicht gefunden: lombok
        requires lombok;
                 ^
...\src\main\java\module-info.java:6: Fehler: Modul nicht gefunden: jakarta.jakartaee.web.api
        requires jakarta.jakartaee.web.api;
                                      ^
...\src\main\java\module-info.java:7: Fehler: Modul nicht gefunden: slf4j.api
        requires slf4j.api;
```

Maven compilation and compilation within IDEs work fine (no module not found messages). The `module-info.java` contains the following lines:

```
module ...api
{
    exports ...api;

    requires lombok;
    requires jakarta.jakartaee.web.api;
    requires slf4j.api;
}
```

Any idea why openliberty does not find the modules? The complete application consists of multiple maven modules that do not show these messages. However the application seems to run without problems. Is it safe to ignore those messages

Comment: The "Source compilation had errors" message sounds like something you'd see from the Liberty Maven or Gradle plugins' "dev mode".   I wonder if something could be happening along the lines of dev mode not being able to compile certain files, but they are already compiled or packaged elsewhere, so you are running OK?    Is there a sample project or recreate you might be able to point to?  What version of Java are you using?